# Enabling copying to clipboard in vim editor

Tags: vim

How do i enable the copy pasting from vim to os clipboard?

I have seen that adding a + sign after the yanking command enables the copy to clipboard. But how do i enable this feature in my vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *prepend* a register name before a `y`ank, `p`aste, etc. command via `"{reg}`, e.g. for a yank into the first named register `a`, that would be `"ayy`.

The register `+` corresponds to the system clipboard, on Linux systems, there's a slightly different register `*` for the X selection. See `:help registers` for details.

As you've found out, you can change the default target register via `:set clipboard=unnamed[plus]`.

Comment: More precisely, `:help quotestar` and `:help quoteplus`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

worked like a charm.